# How to read from the CD drive using Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, cd-rom

I have been trying to write an Audio CD ripper in Java so I can learn how they work. I can't seem to figure out how to actually read the songs off CD drive. I have managed to open the .cda files but there not very useful unless I can access the sectors on the CD. I've tried to open the D: drive (which is the CD drive on my computer) using the code below, but it gives File Not Found errors. I'm guessing this is because the CD drive is not a file. Is there any other type of Input Stream or is there a different way I can read from the CD drive. I've been searching for a long time and there is nothing that I can find that would help.

```
public class learning 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {   
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream( "D:\\" );
    }
}
```

The specific error message is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at learning.main(learning.java:5)
```

Cheers Daniel

Comment: I doubt that an audio CD is available in the file system.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you mean

Comment: `FIleInputStream` reads from the file system. The audio CD doesn't conain files.

Comment: Ahh right yea, i was wondering if there was a different Input Stream that could open a CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an OS project for this: [Ripper](http://www.jsresources.org/apps/ripper.html).

The magic is in the [GrabEncodePanel.java](http://jsresources.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jsresources/jsresources/apps/ripper/src/org/jsresources/apps/ripper/GrabEncodePanel.java?revision=1.3&view=markup), in the `getCDDADir()` and `getCDDAStream()` functions (I'm afraid to post the actual source, as then I'd have to post the license too...)

**EDIT** I learnt something today too: this is only straightforward on Linux according to [this FAQ](http://jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#cdda)

Comment: When i tried to use "URL url = new URL("cdda:/dev/cdrom");" is said "unknown protocol : cdda"

Comment: @DanielBraithwaite I edited my answer, it seems that this method works only in Linux...

Comment: Well, it's kinda the same on any OS: Get a handle to the actual device and read off it. It's just that Unix-likes have those in the accessible file system whereas e.g. Windows has a higher-level hierarchy containing those, usually unavailable to abstractions such as Java.